# D3 .remove() method not working when chained with transitions

Tags: d3.js

**Added jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/crXK3/

This is probably just a newbie mistake, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it...

This is the code that I tried to use, but was unable to make it work:

```
            gridLines = gridLinesG.selectAll("line")
                .data(xScale.ticks(d3.time.months));

            gridLines
                .exit()
                .transition()
                .duration(transitionTime)
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("x2", 0)
                .remove();

            gridLines
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "gridLine")
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("x2", 0)
                .attr("y1", 0);
```

But if I do this instead of just chaining the exit block it works just fine:

```
            gridLines
                .exit()
                .attr("class", "removeLine");
            d3.selectAll(".removeLine")
                .transition()
                .duration(transitionTime)
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("x2", 0)
                .remove();
```

Or, if I do it without the transition it works just fine too:

```
            gridLines
                .exit()
                //.transition()
                //.duration(transitionTime)
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("x2", 0)
                .remove();
```

Can somebody explain what I'm missing?

Comment: @AndyThornton -- I did as you suggested, and put a [jsfiddle together](http://jsfiddle.net/crXK3/).  I now see the issue -- another transition block conflicting with the former -- but I still would have expected to see the `.remove()` method work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you're handling the lines that need to be moved. In your code, you're reselecting those lines after initialising the transitions. Because of the transition the exiting lines are not immediately removed and hence picked up by your reselection. This means that the exiting lines are moved by both transitions (which is why the animation looks a bit weird) and then removed (which you can't see because they overlap other lines or are outside of the SVG).

The solution is to simply use the existing update selection instead of reselecting, i.e. changing

```
d3.selectAll(".gridLine")
  .transition()
```

to

```
gridLines
    .transition()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding -- two thoughts. #1) I can't see any difference between those two code blocks?  #2) The extra gridlines are actually still there -- they never get removed, as I can still see them in the browser's element inspector.